# How to get value of row in a word table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, hp-uft

I'm trying to delete the last row of a word table when there is no data on a specific row in a Word Table using VBA. But so far all it does is delete the last row and throw an error of a missing object.

I tried setting the Text property as the documentation says like this:

```
Set VCell = objTable2.Cell(j,2).Range.Text
```

But it's not working as it throws an error stating that the string object is required.

This is the code I am using to perform the delete:

```
   If j < 9 Then

        For i = 1 To Ubound(TC_STP_Array)

            objTable2.Rows.Last.Select          

            Set VCell = objTable2.Cell(j,2).Range.Text

            If objTable2.Rows.Last.IsLast and VCell = "" Then
                objTable2.Rows.Last.Cells.Delete
            End If


         Next   
End if
```

The first error I get is:

Object Required:'[string "•"]'

on the line:

```
Set VCell = objTable2.Cell(j,2).Range.Text
```

and when there is data on the row, I get this:

Object Required:'[string "Test•"]'

Any Ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the Set word
VCell = objTable2.Cell(j,2).Range.Text
Since it is not an object and it is only required for objects not strings.